# Swift: Views dismiss themselves on actual device

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, mapkit

I have two views (AnimalDetailView and ReportView) that appear upon tapping on a button and annotation on the MapView. I navigate through the views through navigation links.

When I run the app on the simulator there are no issues. However, when I run it on my actual device both DetailsView and ReportView dismiss themselves right after appearing.

What is the reason behind this?

This is how my NavigationView is setup on the MapView.

```
ZStack {
            // NAVIGATION LINK FOR ANIMAL DETAIL VIEW
            NavigationLink(destination: AnimalDetailView(animalAnnotation: animalAnnotation), tag: "animal_detail_view_tag", selection: $annotaionSelection) { EmptyView()
            }
            
            MapModel().onAnnotationTapped(perform: { annotation in
                
                // HERE YOU GET ANNOTATION TAPPED CALLBACKS
                if annotation is AnimalAnnotation {
                    self.animalAnnotation = annotation as? AnimalAnnotation
                    annotaionSelection = "animal_detail_view_tag"
                }else if annotation is ShelterAnnotation {
                    self.shelterAnnotation = annotation as? ShelterAnnotation
                    showingAlert = true
                }
                
            }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text(self.shelterAnnotation?.title ?? ""),
                      message: Text("Veteriner veya barınağı arayarak yaralı hayvanın durumunu bildir."),
                      primaryButton: .default(Text("Barınağı ara"),
                                              action: {callNumber(phoneNumber: "\(self.shelterAnnotation?.number ?? 0)" )}),
                      secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("İptal")))
            }
            
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ReportView(),
                label: {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("AnbulanceBlue"))
                        Text("YARALI HAYVAN BİLDİR")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }).offset(y: 260)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Çıkış yap") {
                    print("çıkış yap")
                    try! Auth.auth().signOut()
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false,forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                    
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(false)
```

The NavigationView is initiated on the first screen of launch like below:

```
ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    if self.status {
                        
                        MapView()
                        
                    } else {
                           
                        VStack {
                            Image("AnbulanceLogo")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            Text("Anbulance")
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("AnbulanceBlue"))
                                .font(.system(size: 40))
                                .padding(.bottom, 100.0)
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: LoginView(),
                                label: {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .padding()
                                        Text("Giriş yap")
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    }
                                })
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: SignUpView(),
                                label: {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("AnbulanceBlue"))
                                        Text("Kaydol")
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
                        self.status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: could you try adding `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `NavigationView`

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.